Allure Maven - How to pass arguments that you can pass to the allure binary?
I can do the following from Commandline
$ allure generate --single-file --name "My Service" path/to/allure-results 

How do I pass the same switches through maven?
Something like
mvn allure:report --single-file --name "My Service"

